# How to restrict DBpedia abstract result to English only

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm querying DBpedia for the title and abstract of a place-name in English only. The query works, but it returns the results in seven languages.

This is my query:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?wikipedia_data_field_name ?wikipedia_data_field_abstract
WHERE {
    ?wikipedia_data foaf:name "Ballyhaunis"@en; foaf:name 
    ?wikipedia_data_field_name; dbpedia-owl:abstract ?wikipedia_data_field_abstract.
  }
```

[SPARQL result](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fwikipedia_data_field_name%20%3Fwikipedia_data_field_abstract%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwikipedia_data%20foaf%3Aname%20%22Ballyhaunis%22%40en%3B%20foaf%3Aname%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwikipedia_data_field_name%3B%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fwikipedia_data_field_abstract.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20)

I tried to add a filter using various permutations of

```
FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), 'en'))
```

but then the query returned no results. I can't see any other property in the corresponding page (http://dbpedia.org/page/Ballyhaunis) that I might be able to filter by. How can I restrict the results to show only the English abstract?

Comment: You shouldn't compare language tags with `=`, but with `langMatches`.  That is, you'd do `filter langMatches(lang(?abstract),'en')`, just like you did in the first query.

Comment: But if you found a solution, please post it as an answer to the question, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With thanks to @Joshua Taylor for advice on the correct way to compare language tags, here is a better answer that works.

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
    PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    SELECT ?wikipedia_data_field_name ?wikipedia_data_field_abstract
    WHERE {
        ?wikipedia_data foaf:name "Ballyhaunis"@en; foaf:name 
        ?wikipedia_data_field_name; dbpedia-owl:abstract ?wikipedia_data_field_abstract.
        FILTER langMatches(lang(?wikipedia_data_field_abstract),'en')
      }
```

[SPARQL result](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fwikipedia_data_field_name%20%3Fwikipedia_data_field_abstract%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fwikipedia_data%20foaf%3Aname%20%22Ballyhaunis%22%40en%3B%20foaf%3Aname%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fwikipedia_data_field_name%3B%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fwikipedia_data_field_abstract.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fwikipedia_data_field_abstract%29%2C%27en%27%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%0D%0A)